# Returning macro from function c++

Tags: c++, macros

So I've got a few define statements at the top of my program

```cpp
#define foo bar
#define three 3
```

etc.

My question is, if I were to have a function that were to say

```cpp
#define foo bar
string returnDef(){
return foo;
}

int main(){
    string foobar = returnDef();
    return 0;
}
```

Would I be returning the message `foo` or would I be returning the definition of `foo`, `bar`?

Comment: Macros are just text replacement. `foo` will be replaced by `bar`. What that means depends on how `bar` is declared, which you didn't show. Please try to make a complete example. Also as general tip: Try to avoid macros where possible.

Comment: You could also (try to) compile it to see what happens!

Comment: @walnut Yes, I've heard that macros are good to avoid, however, in this particular use case they've become necessary.

Comment: *"they've become necessary."*. I doubt it: `constexpr int three = 3;` for the second MACRO, and probably similar for the first MACRO (but missing `bar` definition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo` instances in the source code will be replaced with `bar` instances even before the source code gets compiled. This is called *preprocessing* and it gets kicked in before the compiler. The compiler won't see a statement like `return foo` instead it will see `return bar`.

Therefore you are returning `bar` (Let `bar` be something that you've defined elsewhere) from the function in this instance.